# Memory leak while uploading files

Tags: node.js, formidable

I'm trying to upload a file(30GB) using formidable.Whenever upload starts ram increases drastically and almost it's using 99% of ram.
Here is my upload logic..

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
var path;
var randomFilename;
var UUID;
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
encodingModule.generateUUID(function(uuid){
    UUID = uuid;
});
form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
  console.log(file.name);      
  file.path = null;
  randomFilename = UUID+'.'+file.name.split('.').pop();
  path = file.path = "./ContentCache/"+randomFilename;
});

form.on('end', function(){
    encodingModule.getMetadata(path,function(data){   
         parseApp.update('ContentFile', req.query.objectId, {'fileId':randomFilename, 'videoCodec':data.streams[0].codec_name, 'videoBitrate':data.format.bit_rate, 'audioCodec':data.streams[1].codec_name, 'audioBitrate':data.streams[1].bit_rate, 'resolutionX':data.streams[0].width, 'resolutionY':data.streams[0].height}, function(err,response){
            if(err){
                console.log("metadata:error updating object");
            }
            console.log(response);
         }); 
    });     
    console.log('Local: Upload Successfull..!');
    res.send({msg: "Local: Successfully Uploaded!", objectId: req.query.objectId}); 
    videoQueue.add({video: path, filename:randomFilename, objectId:req.query.objectId});  
}); 

//On upload error
form.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Local: Error occured while uploading: '+err);
});

//on abort
form.on('aborted', function(){
   console.log('Upload aborted'); 
});

//Azure upload
onFinished(req, function (err, req) {
         azureUpload(req.query.objectId, randomFilename, path, function(result){
            console.log(result);
    });       
});      

//Parse incoming nodejs request
form.parse(req);
});
```

Here I pick a file from my PC and upload it to virtual machine where my node server is hosted.After upload ends it encodes(logic is in another file which we dont want).So whenever upload starts ram usage drastically increases from 10% to 99% within 15 minutes.How to solve this? Is there any problem with my upload logic.Here I use express but I don't use body parser

Answer (score 0):

First, how much RAM does your machine have ?

I'm not familiar with the internals of `formidable` but maybe you should try to open a file StreamWriter and write to the file as the chunks are coming in.

From the formidable documentation :

```
form.onPart = function(part) {
  part.addListener('data', function() {
    // Here you should write 'part' to your StreamWriter
  });
}
```

This might help take off the load from the RAM and have the file on disk

Comment: I have 7 GB of RAM and the VM is ubuntu 14.04